# prep scratch org with 2 currencies

Tags: salesforcedx

I know that we can insert currencies via `sfdx force:data:tree:import -f CurrencyTypes.json` where CurrencyTypes.json is the below. But if I wanted to add 2 currencies how do I need to change the JSON file? Could someone please advise. OR do I need to create separate file for each currency?

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "CurrencyType",
        "referenceId": "ref1"
      },
      "IsoCode": "INR",
      "DecimalPlaces": 2,
      "ConversionRate": 1.5,
      "IsActive":true,
      "IsCorporate": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some tinkering I figured it out. I tested it. It worked! Kind of looks obvious now but I struggled with this for quite a bit. Just the process of asking the question StackExchange could have helped.

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "CurrencyType",
        "referenceId": "ref1"
      },
      "IsoCode": "GBP",
      "DecimalPlaces": 2,
      "ConversionRate": 2,
      "IsActive":true,
      "IsCorporate": false
        ,
      "IsoCode": "EUR",
      "DecimalPlaces": 2,
      "ConversionRate": 2,
      "IsActive":true,
      "IsCorporate": false
    }
  ]
}
```